# Creating table using Python3 / sqlite3 with unknown number of columns

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, class

I have a Python class:

```
class Database:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(‘database.db’)
    c = conn.cursor()

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Inside this class I have a  multiple methods  that I will use with my Database class such as:

```
def create_table(self, table_name, *args):
    pass

def add_user(self):
    pass

def remove_user(self):
    pass
```

And so on. 
My question is: how do I use *args with my ‘create_table’ function if I am not sure how many columns I will have. For example I know I will have first, last and pay columns, than my function will look like this:

```
def create_table(self, table_name, *args):
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE ‘{}’ (‘{}’ text, ‘{}’ text, ‘{}’ 
    integer).format(self.table_name, self.first, self.last, self.pay)”””)
    c.commit()
```

So if I want to create table I can do this:

```
Item = Database()
Item.create_table('employees', ‘First_name’, ’Last_name’, 100000)
```

But what if I don’t know how many columns I will have?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_table(self, tableName, *args,):
    columns = ''
    for i in args:
        columns += i
        columns += ' '
    message = '"""CREATE TABLE {} ({})"""'.format(tableName, columns[:-1])
    return message
```

print(create_table('employees','first', 'text,', 'last', 'text,', 'pay', 'integer'))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how variable your columns are; or the time frame. Seems you have have a base set of definitions and then later, a new column pops up. So assuming your table starts with the 4 you mentioned above.

We run the create table first, then loop over the files, updating as we go, and if we find a new column, we run an ALTER TABLE tableName ADD column_name datatype and then obviously you update based on the key.

Or you can run over the table start to finish and create at once as qafrombayarea suggests. Our json files are just not that disciplined.